# Updating Windows Forms GUI while code is running

Tags: c#, .net, progress-bar

I've run into some problems while using progress bars in Windows Forms. Say I have an algorithm with ten parts that runs on a button click. After each part, I'd want to update a progress bar on the form to 10% further along. However, when code is running, the Windows Form will not respond or update.

What is the correct do show progress on a form while code is running?

Comment: I'd start by taking a look at the BackgroundWorker class.

Comment: MSDN is your friend. The documentation for the BackgroundWorker class is a good place to start. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Threads are good place to start too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a `BackgroundWorker`.
A nice example can be found here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/progressbar

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
    InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
      // Start the BackgroundWorker.
      backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
      for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
      {
        // Wait 100 milliseconds.
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        // Report progress.
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
      }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      // Change the value of the ProgressBar to the BackgroundWorker progress.
      progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
      // Set the text.
      this.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
    }
  }
}
```

Or you can use something like:

```
private void StartButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var t1 = new Thread(() => ProgressBar(value));
    t1.Start();
}

private void ProgressBar(value1)
{
  ProgressBar.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
  {
      ProgresBar.Value++
  }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use TPL for such operations as more standardized, lightweight, robust and extendable
See for ex.: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/10/15/10076552.aspx